# cudaDeviceSynchronize is very slow

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cuda

I have to use the result from a CUDA kernel function at subsequent CPU host code, so just below the kernel function, I'm calling `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`. Then the execution gets very slow, so that the time saving gained by using kernel function has gone.

Originally execution time was reduced to below 100ms using CUDA kernel, but `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` takes 150ms. It makes me wonder whether it is justified to use CUDA in this case. Please clarify if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cudaDeviceSynchronize()` will wait until the kernel is complete, so it's more likely that the performance of your kernel is slow and the synchronise is simply waiting for the kernel to complete. You should profile your code with the [Visual Profiler](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html) to see whether it is actually your kernel that is taking the time. The profiler should also help you to understand *why* the kernel is slow and to optimise it.